# Navigating to a view of a module from another module in prism

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, prism

I'm building a little complex prism application. Customer requirements obliges me to utilize ModuleA features in ModuleB.

My question is whether it is breaking prism's decoupling purpose when I reference ModuleA namespace in ModuleB  and navigate to its views. If yes then how can I resolve this ?

Comment: Please do not change the question into something entirely different! Ask a new question instead!

Comment: I'm sorry I was lead to this cause I'm banned from asking questions, I did what's mentioned on meta but didn't work. Thanks for your undestanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `IEventAggregator` and publish/subscribe to weak events (`CompositePresentationEvent<TPayload>`) through it.

[Here is a sample.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample)

[Here is the relevant msdn link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

Comment: I have rolled back the question to its original. I'm not sure if this invalidates your current answer. I'm sorry if it does, but the question should not have been completely changed in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418957%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) [incarnations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.region.requestnavigate%28v=pandp.40%29) of the `RequestNavigate` method (which is the recommended way to begin navigation) intentionally specify views as URIs specifically so that the actual type of the view does not need to be specified inside module code.

Resolution of the actual types from names and of instances from the types is done by the region manager and the container respectively, both of which are configured during the application's bootstrap sequence and do not belong to any specific module.

How exactly are you currently navigating across module boundaries?

Comment: You don't usually navigate in a WPF app, that's for SilverLight. How does this relate to communication between modules?

Comment: @Baboon: Please refer to [the original version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12062936/revisions) of the question, which has since been edited into an entirely different question.

Comment: I see, however I'm not sure how this is dealt with oO.